# I dont understand what those values in the curly bracket represent

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, python-2.7, formatting

I was working with an online tutorial and the author used
`output_string = "Time left: {0:02}:{1:02}".format(minutes, seconds)` but I don't understand what the values in `{0:02}` and `{1:02}` are for.

Comment: you've tagged [string] and [formatting], there's a hint

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format ... https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax ... https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language

Comment: Related [String formatting: % vs. .format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/string-formatting-vs-format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
output_string = "Time left: {0:02}:{1:02}".format(minutes, seconds)
```

- `{...}` is called the replacement field. It contains *instructions* on what is supposed to go there and how it is supposed to look.
- `0:02` - the value on the left side of the colon is the field name. It specifies what replaces the replacement field - in this case it is an index, `0`. The first argument of `.format()` will replace this replacement field.
- `0:02` - the value on the right side of the colon specifies *how it looks* - the format spec. In this case it specifies a width of 2 characters and if the replacement only has one character to fill (from the left) with `'0'`.

---

[Format String Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)
[Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)

Comment: Thanks very much. I understand fully well now